# How to restrict the popup on a back button press

Tags: c#-4.0

I had a page lets say User.aspx. It shows all users on a grid.On clicking view column a a row , a pop up appear that display user details. Now close the pop up and go to another page directly. Lets say CompanyDetails.aspx. Now on clicking browser back button server appear as page redirect to user details page not user page(User.aspx).How can I directly go to (User.aspx) without opening the pop up.

Thanks